# Почему вино - сухое?

Tags: этимология

Задумался: а почему, собственно, вино без добавления спирта называют сухим? А крепленое, что, мокрое?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы немного путаете терминологию. Вслед, впрочем, за многими любителями. 
Сухим называют вино с пониженным содержанием сахара, антоним - "сладкое" вино.

Вино же без добавления спирта называют натуральным, а с таким добавлением - крепленым.
Крепление (крепеж) - процедура, прямо направленная на повышение спиртосодерджания (оборотов), часто  за счет собственно качества вина, хотя, например, настоящий марочный портвейн - вино весьма дорогое.

Добавление же сахара не приводит напрямую к увеличению крепости вина (хотя как побочный результат это возможно), поэтому эти технологии не следует путать. Хотя сладкие вина обычно в "линейке" стоят на последних местах по качеству, содержание сахара еще не есть признак дешевого вина. Хересы (настоящие, т.е. прошедшие процесс хересизации) вина поистине драгоценные: сладкие, но натуральные.

Это базовые вещи, поскольку повышение крепости у дешевого вина тоже часто достигается введением сахара, разобраться в конкретном случае не так просто, что и порождает недоразумения. Но это все уже к сомелье, не к лингвистам.

Касательно же названий. В отношении содержания спирта названия самодоcтаточны, по поводу же сахара: термин "сухой", видимо, напоминает о том, что в любое, хоть сколько-нибудь качественное, сладкое вино сахар вводится не засыпкой (как часто поступают производители "бормртухи"), а сиропом. Хотя тут я в деталях не разбирался.